# Maple converting vectors to data to plot

Tags: maple

I have a list of vectors, like this:

```
{x = 7, y = 0.}, {x = 2.5, y = 0.}, {x = -2.3, y = 0.}, {x = 2.5, y = 2.7}, {x = 2.5, y = -2.7}
```

How do I convert these to data I can plot? I've been trying with the "convert" function, but can't get it to work.

When I manually convert it to something like `[[7, 0], [2.5, 0], [-2.3, 0], [2.5, 2.7], [2.5, -2.7]]` it works, though there has to be an automatic way, right?

A little more info about what I'm doing if you're interested:

I have a function U(x,y), of which I calculate the gradient and then check where it becomes 0, like this:

```
solve(convert(Gradient(U(x, y), [x, y]), set), {x, y});
```

that gives me my list of points. Now I would like to plot these points on a graph.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S:={x = 7, y = 0.}, {x = 2.5, y = 0.}, {x = -2.3, y = 0.},
   {x = 2.5, y = 2.7}, {x = 2.5, y = -2.7}:

T:=map2(eval,[x,y],[S]);

           [[7, 0.], [2.5, 0.], [-2.3, 0.], [2.5, 2.7], [2.5, -2.7]]
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.